# Salesforce test help

Tags: apex, trigger

I have wrote a test that I thought was working... Until about two hours ago. This test assures that when you create a new lead, it also creates the account and contact then links these two together.

I ran this test and looked at the code coverage and to my surprise it said 0% 0/37 lines, however if I run all tests that were already there by default it says 97% of code is covered. What I want to know is why is my test not covering this for some reason?

My trigger:

```
trigger STCONCT on Lead (after insert) {
// Set up the list's for contat, account and case.
  List <Contact> conToInsert = new List <Contact>();
  List <Account> accToInsert = new List <Account>();

// Setup the for method and set the Leads alternative name.
    for( Lead l : Trigger.new ) {
// Define the contact, account and cases.
        Contact c = new Contact();
        Account a = new Account();

// Setting the Contacts details
        c.Title = l.Title;
        c.FirstName = l.FirstName;
        c.LastName = l.LastName;
        c.Email = l.Email;
        c.Phone = l.Phone;
        c.MobilePhone = l.MobilePhone;
        c.Fax = l.Fax;
        c.Description = l.Description;
        c.MailingCity = l.City;
        c.MailingCountry = l.Country;
        c.MailingStreet = l.Street;
        c.MailingPostalCode = l.PostalCode;
// Setting the Accounts details
        a.Name = l.Lastname + ', ' + l.FirstName;
        a.BillingCity = l.City;
        a.BillingCountry = l.Country;
        a.BillingStreet = l.Street;
        a.BillingPostalCode = l.PostalCode;
        a.AnnualRevenue = l.AnnualRevenue;
        a.Website = l.Website;
        a.NumberOfEmployees = l.NumberOfEmployees;
        a.NumberofLocations__c = l.NumberofLocations__c;
        a.Rating = l.Rating;
        a.Description = l.Description;
        a.Fax = l.Fax;
        a.Phone = l.Phone;
// Set up the insertion for account.
        accToInsert.add(a);

// Trying the insertion
        try {
            insert accToInsert;
// Setting details needed after the acc is inserted.
            c.AccountId = a.Id;
// Setup the insertion of contact and inserting it.
            conToInsert.add(c);
            insert conToInsert;
        } catch(System.DmlException e) {
            System.debug(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My test:

```
@isTest
public class LeadTest {

    @testSetup static void setLeadDetails() {
// Set up the new lead
        Lead newLead = new Lead();
        newLead.Title = 'Mr';
        newLead.AnnualRevenue = 18000;
        newLead.City = 'Mitcham';
        newLead.Street = 'Wood Street';
        newLead.Country = 'United Kingdom';
        newLead.Description = 'A test description';
        newLead.Company = 'BookingBug';
        newLead.Email = 'test@test.org';
        newLead.Fax = '111222333';
        newLead.FirstName = 'Adam';
        newLead.LastName = 'Parker';
        newLead.Industry = 'Technology';
        newLead.MobilePhone = '07999888777';
        newLead.NumberOfEmployees = 4;
        newLead.NumberofLocations__c = 2;
        newLead.Phone = '07111222333';
        newLead.PostalCode = 'CR4 4JT';
        newLead.Rating = 'Hot';
        newLead.Website = 'www.lead.com';
// Don't forget to insert the newLead object;
         insert newLead;    
    }

    static testmethod void checkContactInsert() {
// Get the contact(This should be the only contact)
        Contact resultantContact = [SELECT Title, FirstName, LastName, 
                                           Email, Phone, MobilePhone,
                                           Fax, Description, MailingCity,
                                           MailingCountry, MailingStreet, 
                                           MailingPostalCode, AccountId FROM Contact LIMIT 1];

// Assure the resultantContact fields are the expected results;
       System.assertEquals('Mr', resultantContact.Title);
       System.assertEquals('Adam', resultantContact.FirstName);
       System.assertEquals('Parker', resultantContact.LastName);
       System.assertEquals('test@test.org', resultantContact.Email);
       System.assertEquals('07111222333', resultantContact.Phone);
       System.assertEquals('07999888777', resultantContact.MobilePhone);
       System.assertEquals('111222333', resultantContact.Fax);
       System.assertEquals('A test description', resultantContact.Description);
       System.assertEquals('Mitcham', resultantContact.MailingCity);
       System.assertEquals('Wood Street', resultantContact.MailingStreet);
       System.assertEquals('United Kingdom', resultantContact.MailingCountry);
       System.assertEquals('CR4 4JT', resultantContact.MailingPostalCode);
    }

    static testmethod void checkAccountDetails() {
// Get the account(This should be the only account)
        Account resultantAccount = [SELECT Name, AnnualRevenue, Website, 
                                           NumberOfEmployees, NumberofLocations__c,
                                           Rating, Description, Fax, 
                                           Phone, BillingCity, 
                                           BillingCountry, BillingStreet, 
                                           BillingPostalCode FROM Account LIMIT 1];
// Assure the resultantAccount fields are the expected results.
       System.assertEquals('Parker, Adam', resultantAccount.Name);
       System.assertEquals(18000, resultantAccount.AnnualRevenue);
       System.assertEquals('www.lead.com', resultantAccount.Website);
       System.assertEquals(4, resultantAccount.NumberOfEmployees);
       System.assertEquals(2, resultantAccount.NumberofLocations__c);
       System.assertEquals('Hot', resultantAccount.Rating);
       System.assertEquals('A test description', resultantAccount.Description);
       System.assertEquals('111222333', resultantAccount.Fax);
       System.assertEquals('07111222333', resultantAccount.Phone);
       System.assertEquals('Mitcham', resultantAccount.BillingCity);
       System.assertEquals('Wood Street', resultantAccount.BillingStreet);
       System.assertEquals('United Kingdom', resultantAccount.BillingCountry);
       System.assertEquals('CR4 4JT', resultantAccount.BillingPostalCode);

// Get the contacts accountID
       Contact resultantContactID = [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
// Assure the contacts accountID is correct.
       System.assertEquals(resultantContactID.AccountId, resultantAccount.Id); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to do insert in test method inside, not in @testSetup? That would mean that trigger explicitly runs in tests. 
Also, if you run tests using developers console, sometimes code coverage is weirdly calculated. I would recommend to start worry if there are test issues during deployment

Comment: Just added it to the testmethod but I still get the same result

Comment: are you running test from Developer console ?

Comment: Yes, I am not 100% sure to do a deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [**known issue of Winter '16**](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMoyAAE) release which scheduled to be fixed in Spring '16 Path 2.0, current status is release in progress.

So as interim solution while running the test method make sure **"Always run Asynchronously"** checkbox is checked as shown below

[image]

Comment: awesome!!!!! :)

Comment: Hi @Himanshu. I have seen this as a solution to tests many times, but why does it work? Could you explain a bit more? thanks :)

Comment: @mkorman I have updated the answer with more details.